# Mapping data to new Worksheet using PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I'm having trouble in mapping my data to my new worksheet using PHPExcel.

I want to map my data on a new worksheet in **A4** but somehow its not working. I tried to map it in a different column like **F** and it works fine. Can you give me hints on how to map my data in the correct column?

[image]

Here's my code:

```
$incentive = "select * from incentive";

$connect = @mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) 
or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . 
mysql_errno()); 
//select database 
$Db = @mysql_select_db($dbname, $connect) 
or die("Couldn't select database:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . 
mysql_errno()); 
//execute query 
$resultincentive = @mysql_query($incentive,$connect) 
or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . 
mysql_errno()); 

error_reporting(E_ALL);

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel(); 
$objPHPExcel->createSheet();

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);  
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'Company Name:');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A2', 'Sales Incentive for the 
Month of:');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D1', 'Date:');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A3', 'Date');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B3', 'Total Sales');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C3', 'Sales Net of Vat');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D3', 'Sales Quota');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E3', 'Incentive Amount');

$rowCount2  = 1;

 while($rowincentive = mysql_fetch_array($resultincentive)){

 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A4'.$rowCount2, 
$rowincentive['DATE']);


 $rowCount2++;
 }
 // Rename 2nd sheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Incentive');
```

Comment: `'A4'.$rowCount2` is going to give you cells A41, A42, A43... A49, A410, A411, etc.... is that really what you want?

Comment: @MarkBaker sorry for not responding to your comment because of my busy schedule, I've assigned my variable $rowCount2 = 4, so that I can get my starting row at A4 :) thnx for the comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for not answering the question... I found out how to do it and haven't answered it for the past few weeks because of my busy schedule...

I just adjusted it using the $rowCount2

```
$rowCount2  = 4;
```

This gives me the column of A4 :)